# About how to upload PDF file and show it

Tags: pdf

I can't figure out how to do like this page http://service.citroen.com/ddb/modeles/c5/c5_c5/ed10-07/de_de/4_21_c5-al-ed10-2007.pdf I embed usually the PDF from slideside in my site but people cant dowload from because they need to have an accoount. So technically how ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PDF viewer component for displaying the PDF. You will have to configure the PDF component so as to limit download and print options.

[image]
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=329&t=Display_PDF_without_saving_file_to_disk_in_WinForms_and_ASP_NET